# Using bson.ObjectId in Pydantic v2

Tags: python, pydantic, bson

I found [some examples](https://github.com/mongodb-developer/mongodb-with-fastapi/blob/master/app.py#L13C1-L28C43) on how to use ObjectId within `BaseModel` classes. Basically, this can be achieved by creating a Pydantic-friendly class as follows:

```py
class PyObjectId(ObjectId):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if not ObjectId.is_valid(v):
            raise ValueError("Invalid objectid")
        return ObjectId(v)

    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls, field_schema):
        field_schema.update(type="string")
```

However, this seems to be for Pydantic v1, as this mechanisms have been superseeded by the `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` classmethod. However, I have been unable to achieve an equivalent solution with Pydantic v2. Is is possible? What validators do I need? I tried to refactor things but was uanble to get anything usable.

Answer (score 10):

None of the above worked for me. I've followed [Pydantic documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/custom/#handling-third-party-types) to come up with this solution:

```py
from typing import Annotated, Any, Callable

from bson import ObjectId
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, Field, GetJsonSchemaHandler
from pydantic.json_schema import JsonSchemaValue
from pydantic_core import core_schema


class _ObjectIdPydanticAnnotation:
    # Based on https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/custom/#handling-third-party-types.

    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
        cls,
        _source_type: Any,
        _handler: Callable[[Any], core_schema.CoreSchema],
    ) -> core_schema.CoreSchema:
        def validate_from_str(input_value: str) -> ObjectId:
            return ObjectId(input_value)

        return core_schema.union_schema(
            [
                # check if it's an instance first before doing any further work
                core_schema.is_instance_schema(ObjectId),
                core_schema.no_info_plain_validator_function(validate_from_str),
            ],
            serialization=core_schema.to_string_ser_schema(),
        )

PydanticObjectId = Annotated[
    ObjectId, _ObjectIdPydanticAnnotation
]


class User(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(populate_by_name=True)

    id: PydanticObjectId = Field(alias='_id')
    name: str


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/user/{id}")
def get_usr(id: str) -> User:
    # Here we would connect to MongoDB and return the user.
    # Method is here just to test that FastAPI will not complain about the "User" return type
    pass


# Some usage examples

user1 = User(_id=ObjectId('64cca8a68efc81fc425aa864'), name='John Doe')
user2 = User(_id='64cca8a68efc81fc425aa864', name='John Doe')
assert user1 == user2  # Can use str and ObjectId interchangeably

# Serialization
assert repr(user1) == "User(id=ObjectId('64cca8a68efc81fc425aa864'), name='John Doe')"
assert user1.model_dump() == {'id': '64cca8a68efc81fc425aa864', 'name': 'John Doe'}
assert user1.model_dump_json() == '{"id":"64cca8a68efc81fc425aa864","name":"John Doe"}'

# Deserialization
user2 = User.model_validate_json('{"id":"64cca8a68efc81fc425aa864","name":"John Doe"}')
user3 = User.model_validate_json('{"_id":"64cca8a68efc81fc425aa864","name":"John Doe"}')
assert user1 == user2 == user3

user4 = User(_id=ObjectId(), name='Jane Doe')  # Default ObjectId constructor

# Validation
user5 = User(_id=ObjectId('qwe'), name='Jack Failure')  # Will throw bson.errors.InvalidId
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Bojan Bogdanovic, this worked well for me so far.
But I still can't use `PydanticObjectId` as path or query parameter (e.g.: `def get_usr(id: PydanticObjectId) -> User:` which I used to do in v1.  
I get the exception `fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field!` (even though it is actually the *query* field causing the problem)
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have an answer here, I simply use `str`s as the type. I guess the only advantage to using `PydanticObjectId` here is documentation? In that case I would look into how you could document that it's a string of the format used for ObjectId?

Comment: Well not only documentation, but also validation since the handler method wouldn't even get called and the client would receive a properly generated error object, if the id was in a wrong format. But thanks anyway, maybe someone else has an idea?

Comment: Using the `PyObjectId ` implementation from the pydantic-mongo package solved this for me. I added a separate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77105412/5106474

Answer (score 10):

None of the previous solutions worked for me when I want to use `PyObjectId` not only as type of a Pydantic model field but also for input parameters (path or query).

But the `ObjectIdField` class in the most recent release of the [pydantic-mongo](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic-mongo/#description) package seems to work fine with Pydantic v2 and exactly reproduces the behaviour which I was used to from the Pydantic v1 implementation.

If you do not want to an additional dependency, you could also directly use the `ObjectIdField` implementation from the package sources to find at:
https://github.com/jefersondaniel/pydantic-mongo/blob/f517e7161a8fb10002ef64881f092f6f84b40971/pydantic_mongo/fields.py

**UPDATE for Pydantic v2.4**

This approach went well on **Pydantic 2.3.0**, but on **Pydantic 2.4.2** the the OpenAPI schema generation fails with the following exception when trying to access */docs*:

```
pydantic.errors.PydanticInvalidForJsonSchema: 
Cannot generate a JsonSchema for core_schema.PlainValidatorFunctionSchema 
({'type': 'no-info', 
'function': <bound method ObjectIdField.validate of <class 'ObjectIdField'>>})
```

I could solve this by excluding the validator function from the json_schema only. This is the full implementation, which works for me with Pydantic 2.4.2:

```py
from typing import Any

from bson import ObjectId
from pydantic_core import core_schema

class PyObjectId(str):
    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
            cls, _source_type: Any, _handler: Any
    ) -> core_schema.CoreSchema:
        return core_schema.json_or_python_schema(
            json_schema=core_schema.str_schema(),
            python_schema=core_schema.union_schema([
                core_schema.is_instance_schema(ObjectId),
                core_schema.chain_schema([
                    core_schema.str_schema(),
                    core_schema.no_info_plain_validator_function(cls.validate),
                ])
            ]),
            serialization=core_schema.plain_serializer_function_ser_schema(
                lambda x: str(x)
            ),
        )

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, value) -> ObjectId:
        if not ObjectId.is_valid(value):
            raise ValueError("Invalid ObjectId")

        return ObjectId(value)
```

Comment: Tried this with Pydantic 2.5.2 and it works!

Answer (score 7):

To migrate the old-fashioned `PyObjectId` to the newest [pydantic-v2](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/) version, the easiest way is to use an [annotated validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#annotated-validators).

```
from typing import Any
from typing import Annotated, Union
from bson import ObjectId
from pydantic import PlainSerializer, AfterValidator, WithJsonSchema

def validate_object_id(v: Any) -> ObjectId:
    if isinstance(v, ObjectId):
        return v
    if ObjectId.is_valid(v):
        return ObjectId(v)
    raise ValueError("Invalid ObjectId")

PyObjectId = Annotated[
    Union[str, ObjectId],
    AfterValidator(validate_object_id),
    PlainSerializer(lambda x: str(x), return_type=str),
    WithJsonSchema({"type": "string"}, mode="serialization"),
]
```

You can then use it in your model in this way:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic import ConfigDict, Field

class MyCustomModel(BaseModel):
    id: PyObjectId = Field(alias="_id")

    model_config = ConfigDict(arbitrary_types_allowed=True)
```

Test it out using [TypeAdapter](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/usage/type_adapter/):

```
import pytest
from bson import ObjectId
from pydantic import TypeAdapter, ConfigDict
    
@pytest.mark.parametrize("obj", ["64b7992ba8f08069073f1055", ObjectId("64b7992ba8f08069073f1055")])
def test_pyobjectid_validation(obj):
    ta = TypeAdapter(PyObjectId, config=ConfigDict(arbitrary_types_allowed=True))
    ta.validate_python(obj)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("obj", ["64b7992ba8f08069073f1055", ObjectId("64b7992ba8f08069073f1055")])
def test_pyobjectid_serialization(obj):
    ta = TypeAdapter(PyObjectId, config=ConfigDict(arbitrary_types_allowed=True))
    ta.dump_json(obj)
```

This solution works well even with the newest [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) v0.100.0+

Comment: However, this still does not work when using in the FastApi route directly like this:
@report_router.delete("/presets/{_id}")
def delete_preset(request: Request, _id: PyObjectId):

giving the error:
Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that typing.Union[str, bson.objectid.ObjectId] is a valid Pydantic field type.

Comment: running 0.100.1 version of FastAPI

Comment: This approach didn't work for me with Pydantic 2.1.1 and FastAPI 0.100.1. See my answer below.

Comment: @A.B. is there a way to use it as a class (not as a type), like before? I need it, because I also used `PyObjectId` class instead `ObjectId` as well everywhere.

Comment: @Bi0max please see the answer of Bojan Bogdanovic (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837550/9204009), it's the correct way to migrate the old PyObjectId from v1 to v2 without any change.

Answer (score 3):

Just use below PyObjectId class instead of old PyObjectId class which defined [here](https://Just%20use%20below%20PyObjectId%20class%20instead%20of%20old%20PyObjectId%20class%20which%20defined%20here:%20https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/python/python-quickstart-fastapi/).

```
class PyObjectId(ObjectId):
@classmethod
def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
    cls,
    _source_type: Any,
    _handler: GetCoreSchemaHandler,
) -> CoreSchema:
    def validate(value: str) -> ObjectId:
        if not ObjectId.is_valid(value):
            raise ValueError("Invalid ObjectId")
        return ObjectId(value)

    return core_schema.no_info_plain_validator_function(
        function=validate,
        serialization=core_schema.to_string_ser_schema(),
    )

@classmethod
def __get_pydantic_json_schema__(
    cls, _core_schema: CoreSchema, handler: GetJsonSchemaHandler
) -> JsonSchemaValue:
    return handler(core_schema.str_schema())
```

You can continue to use PyObjectId type for inputs (query or path param) and outputs (converts to string and no problem for json response).

Comment: This is the only solution on this page I managed to get properly to serialize and deserialize ObjectIds to/from JSON / strings with Pydantic 2.5.3

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach to solve this Pydantic-V2 is to create an [annotated validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#annotated-validators):

```py
from typing_extensions import Annotated

from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, field_validator
from pydantic.functional_validators import AfterValidator


PyObjectId = Annotated[
    ObjectId,
    AfterValidator(ObjectId.is_valid),
]
```

As far as representing as a string, you probably want to update the annotation, perhaps using a Union with a string, then perform an additional validator which converts to string:

```py
PyObjectId = Annotated[
    Union[ObjectId, str],
    AfterValidator(ObjectId.is_valid),
    AfterValidator(str)
]
```

Test it out using [TypeAdaptor](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/type_adapter/):

```py
from pydantic import TypeAdapter


ta = TypeAdapter(PyObjectId)
ta.validate_python("SOME-STRING")
```

Comment: So this article seems to be the "go to" for understanding how to use Pydantic 1 and MongoDB: https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/python/python-quickstart-fastapi/ - is this idea meant to be a drop in replacement for PyObjectId? Going to try and do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you (like me) we're banging your head against the wall trying to figure out how you can use the ObjectId type when instantiating a pydantic model but wanted it serialized to a string when using it as a response model in a fastAPI endpoint, then fear not!

I used @PhilJay 's answer which worked really well.

The only change I had to make was adding the option when_used="json" to the serialization part of his code:

```
class PyObjectId(str):
@classmethod
def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
        cls, _source_type: Any, _handler: Any
) -> core_schema.CoreSchema:
    return core_schema.json_or_python_schema(
        json_schema=core_schema.str_schema(),
        python_schema=core_schema.union_schema([
            core_schema.is_instance_schema(ObjectId),
            core_schema.chain_schema([
                core_schema.str_schema(),
                core_schema.no_info_plain_validator_function(cls.validate),
            ])
        ]),
        serialization=core_schema.plain_serializer_function_ser_schema(
            lambda x: str(x), when_used="json"
        ),
    )

@classmethod
def validate(cls, value) -> ObjectId:
    if not ObjectId.is_valid(value):
        raise ValueError("Invalid ObjectId")

    return ObjectId(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help others on the V2:

```py
from enum import Enum
from bson import ObjectId
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

from typing import Any
from pydantic_core import core_schema

class PyObjectId(ObjectId):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, value: Any) -> ObjectId:
        """Validates if the provided value is a valid ObjectId."""
        if isinstance(value, ObjectId):
            return value
        if isinstance(value, str) and ObjectId.is_valid(value):
            return ObjectId(value)
        raise ValueError("Invalid ObjectId")
    
    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
            cls, _source_type: Any, _handler: Any
    ) -> core_schema.CoreSchema:
        """
        Defines the core schema for FastAPI documentation.
        Creates a JSON schema representation compatible with Pydantic's requirements.
        """
        return core_schema.json_or_python_schema(
            json_schema=core_schema.str_schema(),
            python_schema=core_schema.is_instance_schema(ObjectId)
        )
    
class BaseModelEncoder(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        json_encoders = {ObjectId: str}

class User(BaseModelEncoder):
    id: PyObjectId = Field(default_factory=PyObjectId, alias="_id")
    email: str


# How to use (using motor):
# Fetch
# user = User(**await client['db']['users'].find_one({'_id': 'XXX'}))
# Insert
# await client['db']['users'].insert_one(user.model_dump(exclude_none=True, by_alias=True))
```